# fos:elastica:populate new data, whtich is inserted in mysql externally

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

we have a symfony-application, using the FOS\ElasticaBundle\Elastica-Package. All works fine. We have populate the Mysql-Data with ./app/console `fos:elastica:populate --no-debug` . The most data in the app will be edited in the symfony-app, and the sync to ES runs perfect.

Some data comes from external sources direct in the database. We try to refresh the index by

```
./app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset --no-debug --batch-size=8192
```

But it seems, that new data will not populate to ES, we check this directly on search in ES by

```
curl -XGET 'http://<ESHOS>/..../_search?q=_id:<ID_FROM_MYSQL'
```

Is there a way to refresh the ES-Index without resetting the index complete?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I have found the answer: I only have to add in config.yml

```
use_alias: true
```

delete the old index, start ./app/console fos:elastica:populate  --no-debug --batch-size=8192

Comment: I have similar problem, but can't sole it with `use_alias: true`, could you help me?

Comment: So if its the similar problem: possible the first populate was broken. Try deleting the index, than start pouplating (with batch-size=1024), and after finisish, have a look for all documents in ES - the count of documents is higher than the count of the entries in the database-table.